# Easy mesh curves? (Eyelashes)

Tags: modeling, mesh, vertices

I'm trying to do mesh eyelashes at the moment and can't get an easy outward curve for them in any fashion.

Right now, they're straight stiff and need to be curved as seen in the second image:

[image: My model]

[image: Reference model]

Whatever else I tried so far didn't help without sloppy results, like the curve not moving the whole mesh smoothly, or the lash roots being moved as well.

Any easy ways to curve a mesh like this?